# How to mock message chaining with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-mocks

I have a statement like `Model.some_scope.pluck(:a_field)` in a method I'd like to test.

What's the recommended way for me to stub the return value of this chained method call statement with rspec-mocks 3.4.0? I saw that `stub_chain` and `receive_message_chain` are both listed as old syntax on the RSpec website.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way to test that code is to extract a method, e.g.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.some_scope_fields
    some_scope.pluck(:a_field)
  end
end
```

That method can be stubbed without a chain.

However, there are times when it's neither convenient nor idiomatic to do that. For example, it's idiomatic, and not a Law of Demeter violation, to call `create` on an ActiveRecord model's association methods. In those cases,

- if you don't care about method arguments, use `receive_message_chain`. `stub_chain` is deprecated; `receive_message_chain` is not. What [the `receive_message_chain` documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains) says is that "support for stub_chain parity may be removed in future versions". The issue linked to from that documentation makes it clear that "stub chain parity" means the use of `with` with `receive_message_chain`. So do use `receive_message_chain`; just don't use `with` with it.
- if you do care about method arguments, use doubles. For example, for the code you gave,

  ```
  scope = double
  allow(scope).to receive(:pluck).with(:a_field) { # return whatever }
  allow(Model).to receive(:some_scope).with(no_args) { scope }
  ```